# I want to download and save the audio of the link in python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to download and save the audio of the link in python.
How should I write it in beautifulsoup or selenium?
I don't know the answer.

[Link](https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob&tl=en&q=how%27s%20the%20weather%20today?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to download something with Python, there is no reason to use either Selenium or BeautifulSoup. Instead, consider using the requests library:

```
pip install requests
```

And download the mp3 like so:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob&tl=en&q=how%27s%20the%20weather%20today?")
open("file.mp3", "wb").write(response.content)
```

This will download the audio to a file called `file.mp3` in your local directory.

You could also use other alternatrives such as wget and urllib. You could even download the file by running a simple `curl` command:

```
curl -o file.mp3 https://translate.google.com/translate_tts\?ie\=UTF-8\&client\=tw-ob\&tl\=en\&q\=how%27s%20the%20weather%20today\?
```